# NextRouter was not mounted." occurs in storybook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

I am using next13. So I have raised storybook to version7.
However, when I start up story-book, I get the next-route error.
The cause is that I am using router in AppContext. If I comment out the router part, the storybook works.
I am making the transition to the screen according to the error content in the AppContext. (using router).

error

```
NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { initialize, mswDecorator } from 'msw-storybook-addon';

import { AppContextProvider } from '../src/context/AppContextProvider';
import { NextPageWithLayout } from '../src/pages/_app.page';
import {
  mockOrganization,
  mockList,
} from '../src/stories/mocks/msw-handlers';

import 'style/index.css';
import 'style/utils/slider.css';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

initialize();

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  layout: 'fullscreen',
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  msw: {
    handlers: {
      '/organization': mockOrganization(),
      '/master': mockList(),
    },
  },
  chromatic: {
    viewports: [375, 768, 1200],
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  (Story: NextPageWithLayout) => {
    const getLayout = Story.getLayout ?? (page => page);

    return <AppContextProvider>{getLayout(<Story />)}</AppContextProvider>;
  },
  mswDecorator,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Router is properly initialized and mounted in your Storybook setup

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'next/router';
import { initialize, mswDecorator } from 'msw-storybook-addon';

import { AppContextProvider } from '../src/context/AppContextProvider';
import { NextPageWithLayout } from '../src/pages/_app.page';
import {
  mockOrganization,
  mockList,
} from '../src/stories/mocks/msw-handlers';

import 'style/index.css';
import 'style/utils/slider.css';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

initialize();

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  layout: 'fullscreen',
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  msw: {
    handlers: {
      '/organization': mockOrganization(),
      '/master': mockList(),
    },
  },
  chromatic: {
    viewports: [375, 768, 1200],
  },
};

const RouterDecorator = (Story: NextPageWithLayout) => {
  const [isRouterReady, setIsRouterReady] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Router.ready(() => {
      setIsRouterReady(true);
    });
  }, []);

  const getLayout = Story.getLayout ?? (page => page);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {isRouterReady && (
        <AppContextProvider>
          {getLayout(<Story />)}
        </AppContextProvider>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export const decorators = [RouterDecorator, mswDecorator];
```